# Tomcat 9 heap memory setting issue

Tags: java, windows, tomcat, server, tomcat9

Hi my tomcat 9 is running as windows service, the instruction is to set this in the startup script

```
set JAVA_OPTS=-Xms2048m -Xmx2048m;
```

However i think i dont have startup script because it is a service?
so i went to the Configuration and did this instead

[This is the configuration i did](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cH8OB.png)

Is this the correct way?

so i went to the Configuration and add

```
-Xms2048m 
-Xmx2048m
```

in the java options

Answer (score 0):

In the screenshot you shared, there is an "Initial Memory Pool" and a "Maximum Memory Pool". For Xms, set the value 2048 in the "Initial Memory Pool" and for Xmx, set the value 2048 in the "Maximum Memory Pool".

After the change, restart the tomcat service.

Comment: Oh are they the same thing?

Comment: @kkid - What specific changes are you recommending? The screenshot in the question already uses `2048m` for both `Xms` and `Xmx`. (If you really do mean to set the value to `2048`, then that is 2048 bytes, not megabytes.)

Comment: @TonyCheng - it is not uncommon to set `Xms` and `Xmx` to the same value at startup. That means the minimum and maximum memory allocations will be the same amount. So, the server starts, it allocates 2048 megabytes immediately - and then that value does not change over time. By contrast if you set `Xms`  to `2048m` and `Xmx` to `4096m`, then Tomcat will start with 2048 megabytes - but that could increase, over time, to 4096 megabytes. Some people prefer to get the allocation done once, up-front, to avoid the cost of doing further re-allocations over time.